# Is there a way to allocate a fixed number of characters for each digit in JTextArea?

Tags: java, string, swing, printf, jtextarea

Is there a way to get the same result like in `System.out.printf("%4d", n);` but in 
`txtOutput.append(object.getValue() + "\t");`?

The `\t` allocates too many fixed number of characters for each digit and i need less.

Comment: Are you aware of method [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) in class `String` ? Also, I think you probably want to use a fixed-width font in your `txtOutput`. Would that be a `JTextArea` ?

Comment: @Abra *"Would that be a `JTextArea`?"* That's what is implied in the title.

Comment: Now i am aware. This solved what i needed. Yes, this is JTextArea

Comment: *The \t allocates too many fixed number of characters for each digit and i need less.* - read the JTextArea API. There is a method that allows you to control the number of characters that are expanded by each tab. The default is 8.